# How can I download the sample app for the google developers?

Tags: download, sample

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/training/getting-started/

the sample app links here:
https://code.google.com/p/iap-python/

Yet I see no place to download the app.

I'm using Windows 7 and Google Chrome browser.

---

THANK YOU!!! Here is the screenshot how to do it:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top toolbar, click "source", then below that click "browse", and on the left click "src". Hope this helps!

Comment: THANK YOU I didn't see that toolbar! You can download the zip at that page. I'll post a screenshot. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: too bad it's useless to me cause it's entirely in python, can't use this on windows. google you suck for giving useless samples. Instead of making a real chrome extension tutorial they linked to a python guide for integrating wallet that is useless for a chrome extension developer. :(